# Are there libCURL bindings for the Go language

Tags: go, libcurl

I have searched web for libCURL bindings for Go language, but failed to find any... I also checked [curl.haxx.se](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/bindings.html) list of bindings with no success for Go. Are there any such project on net?

If such binding don't exists are where any alternative libraries or maybe you could provide some hints how I could implement my own bindings of libCURL?

Thanks

Comment: Simply make a [`http.Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/http/#Request) and execute it with a [`http.Client`](http://golang.org/pkg/http/#Client) to have unlimited possibilities.

Comment: @Zippoxer - this will work for http protocol only...?

Comment: @Daruis: I haven't tested it with HTTPS yet, but it should work like it does with HTTP.

Comment: @Zippoxer - what I had in mind that libcurl supports DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP, but http.Client only supports HTTP/HTTPS...

Comment: You're right (although the `http` package supports WebSocket protocol too if you involve the `websocket` package). You might find other packages supporting what you want here: http://golang.org/pkg/

Comment: There are now libcurl binding in go - https://github.com/andelf/go-curl - but i think its worth asking why there was not heavy demand for this in golang before using - e.g there will be individual libs available for most protocols mentioned which are more focused and often written in pure go. calling libcurl requires cgo, consider the costs of this type of operation (runtime efficiency, program complexity, difficulty debugging, etc.) before doing this, been programming in go for a while now and Ive used most of these protocols without needing curl.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tend to just use http.Client which does enough stuff for me not to need Curl:

http://golang.org/pkg/http/#Client

Comment: This did not answer OP's question, and the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 8):

I found [Cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) utility: "Cgo enables the creation of Go packages that call C code". I will try to create my wrapper of libCURL for Go.

**UPDATED:**

Created github repository [gocurl](https://github.com/dkucinskas/gocurl/).
Initial version of Easy interface, not working yet. But it's a start :)

**UPDATED 2:**

Found better implementation [go-curl](https://github.com/andelf/go-curl)